# Jfreechart: Vertical scroll of the gantt chart

Tags: java, user-interface, drawing, paint, jfreechart

In the Gantt chart if there are large number of tasks, the bars becomes very small and close to one another as shown in the figure, making it difficult to trace the tasks.

[image]

I want to know if it is possible to add a vertical scrollbar in the chart panel and fix the bar sizes, so that the user can just use the scrollbar to trace his tasks.

Update:

An [example](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=18917) of vertical scrollbar is provided in the JFreechart Forum. This may be what is needed for my current chart.

Comment: @trashgod: I think this question has two parts: how to fix the bar size and how to add the vertical scrolling. 
The answer to the bar size is in the link that you provided.
But the answer to the vertical scrolling is in the [link](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=18917) that I gave.
Hence I conclude that this post is not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: The `SlidingGanttCategoryDataset` example cited shows how to incorporate the scroll bar; if you still have trouble, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).